# Converting HTML to Excel with Django

Tags: python, django, excel

I have a reporting module in my Django app that gives the user the ability to see their reports on screen or to export them and have the export opened by Excel.

The export is a cheat. I take the exact same output as the screen version and save it to a file with an .xls extension and 
response = HttpResponse(body, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel') 
and badda-boom, badda-bing I have an Excel file that is lightly formatted, i.e. it respects the css styling that I've applied.

The nice thing for the user is that the file auto-opens in Excel; there aren't any extra steps for them. (find the download, import a text file, etc.)

Unfortunately it looks like Excel 2016 has decided (I'm guessing) that that's a security issue and no longer opens the file.

I'm aware of various python -> Excel tools. openpyxl looks promising. But that's going to require me to touch each report.

So, what I'm looking for is something that would give me what I have now, take an html file and have Excel open it as a native file and recognize the existing formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior change has been noted by Microsoft and there are work arounds, for the user:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3181507

It sounds like they're working on a fix.